# как изменить количество добавляемого товара PHP

Tags: php

Всем привет! Я хочу при отправке формы с измененным количеством товара менять ключ "quantity" в массиве. У меня это получается только у того товара, у которого я меняю это значение, у остальных оно не сохраняется и остается равным 1. Например я отправил  у "товар1" количество 5, оно сохранилось, а если я отправлю еще раз, но уже у другого товара, то у "товар1" количество сбросится до 1, а у нового перезапишется на указанное. То есть я создаю сессионую переменную и сохраняю туда передаваемое через форму число, а потом меняю у товара, с которым совпал id.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если хотите что-бы вам помогли, то пажалуйста покажите код PHP где выполняються эти действия. Вас вопрос это как спросить "Сколько калорий в супе который я ел 5 дней назад" ^-^

Comment: Вывод 1 - когда вы рисуете форму - не учитывается то что лежит в сессии например $_SESSION['quantity'] = [{"id":1,"quantity":5}]''; Если храните в базе - то каждый раз вытаскивайте из базы. Или не перерисовывайте форму а используйте ajax

Comment: `оно сохранилось` - боюсь не сохранилось, иначе бы в следующий раз улетело уже 5, а не 1

Comment: @ПростаMiha добавил

Comment: @Mcile это задача к основному проекту и ее нужно реализовать просто на пхп, да и я бы сам хотел понять как это сделать на чистом пхп

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите держать данные только в сессии без записи в базу и без использования ajax вам необходим структурированный тип данных (например json). В своем примере вы перезаписываете сессию - так как у сессии есть только ключ и значение. Чтобы хранить массив по ключу - рекомендую воспользоваться форматом JSON вот пример

```
$count_arr = [];
if($_SESSION['quantity']){
    try{
        $count_arr = json_decode($_SESSION['quantity'],true);
    } catch (Exception $e) {}
}

$count_arr[$id] = $quantity;

$_SESSION['quantity'] = json_encode($count_arr,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

//exampe
foreach($count_arr as $key_id=>$value_quantity){
    echo 'у товара с id='.$key_id.' количество '.$value_quantity;
}
```

но проще клиенту показывать

```
<input type="number" name="product-<?php echo $product_id; ?>" 
value="<?php echo $product_quantity; ?>"/>
```

тогда и на сервере вы бы использовали  `explode('-',$product_name);`
а сессия выглядела бы так `$_SESSION['product-2']=5;$_SESSION['product-81']=10;`